# Split data frame into smaller ones and push a big dataframe to all executors?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm implementing the following logic using Spark.

1. Get the result of a table with 50K rows.
2. Get another table (about 30K rows).
3. For all the combination between (1) and (2), do some work and get a value.

How about pushing the data frame of (2) to all executors and partition (1) and run each portion on each executor? How to implement it?

```
val getTable(t String) =
  sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map(
    "driver" -> "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
    "url" -> jdbcSqlConn,
    "dbtable" -> s"$t"
  )).load()
  .select("col1", "col2", "col3")

val table1 = getTable("table1")
val table2 = getTable("table2")

// Split the rows in table1 and make N, say 32, data frames
val partitionedTable1 : List[DataSet[Row]] = splitToSmallerDFs(table1, 32) // How to implement it?

val result = partitionedTable1.map(x => {
  val value = doWork(x, table2) // Is it good to send table2 to executors like this?
  value
})
```

Question:

1. How to break a big data frame into small data frames? (repartition?)
2. Is it good to send table2 (pass a big data frame as a parameter) to executors like this?

Answer (score 1):

> > How to break a big data frame into small data frames? (repartition?)

Simple answer would be Yes [repartion](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#repartition(int)) can be a solution.

The challanging question can be, **Would repartitioning a dataframe to smaller partition improve the overall operation?**

Dataframes are already distributed in nature. Meaning that the operation you perform on dataframes like join, groupBy, aggregations, functions and many more are all executed where the data is residing. But the operations such as join, groupBy, aggregations where shuffling is needed, repartition would be void as

1. groupBy operation would shuffle dataframe such that distinct groups would be in the same executor.
2. partitionBy in Window function performs the same way as groupBy
3. join operation would shuffle data in the same manner.

> > Is it good to send table2 (pass a big data frame as a parameter) to executors like this?

Its not good to pass the dataframes as you did. As you are passing dataframes inside transformation so the `table2` would not be visible to the executors.

I would suggest you to use [broadcast variable](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html)

you can do as below

```
val table2 = sparkContext.broadcast(getTable("table2"))
val result = partitionedTable1.map(x => {
  val value = doWork(x, table2.value) 
  value
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean `val result = table1.map(x => {` (not `partitionedTable1`) in the second line of the code in your answer? Since the data frame will be distributed to all the executor by default? So there is no need to manually split it?

Comment: nope. thats not what I meant. I suggested to use dataframe as a broadcast variable and access it in your other functions instead of passing dataframe as an argument.

Comment: Do I need `splitToSmallerDFs()` to split `table1` to `partitionedTable1: List[DataSet[Row]]`? Will the execution of `table1.map(...)` be distributed to all executors?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan why are you using "map" instead of foreach ? what is x here ...dataframe ?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan why to send second dataframe , why not first one also ?